# Kafka JMX not reporting kafka.log:type=LogFlushStats,name=LogFlushRateAndTimeMs

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring

All the guides on monitoring kafka point to Log Flush Rate being a key metric to watch for problems.

We have a modest three node kafka cluster (0.9.x) that we are starting to get serious about. I went ahead and set up prometheus to scrape the metrics (using the jmx_exporter they provide) however I wasn't seeing the Log Flush Rate metrics flowing in. Further examination of the jmx port on one of the brokers reveals that it's not being surfaced.

Specifically I'm looking for this metric kafka.log:type=LogFlushStats,name=LogFlushRateAndTimeMs

I'm not much of a java guy so I'm not sure this isn't just something that can be corrected with additional flags or what. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Headed straight to Stackoverflow to find this post with no answer. After some tests I figured that the metric mentioned shows up in the JMX report only after a kafka log segment roll. Due to setting log.segment.bytes=1073741824 , it was not rolling as fast and so there was nothing to report. Setting this number to a lower amount and also reducing the number of partitions in the target topic forced a faster log roll, therefore the metric was exported. Hope this helps the next visitor. :)

Comment: wow ... > 4 years later, someone finds some answer.